# Loop through worksheets, exclude some and look-up cell value

Tags: excel, vba, loops, worksheet

I have an Excel workbook with several worksheets.

I would like the macro to look at the value of cell "A1" of each worksheet.
If the cell value is less than 8, A1 must be adjusted to 8.
If the cell value is greater than 8, nothing needs to be adjusted.

I have two macros:

```vb
Sub LoopCertain() 'Excel VBA to exclude sheets(1-3)
Dim sh As Worksheet

For Each sh In Sheets
    Select Case sh.Name
    Case Is = "Blad1", "Blad2", "Blad3"
        'No Code here if excluded
    Case Else
        Call X2
    End Select
Next sh

End Sub
```

and

```vb
Sub X2()
'declare a variable
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet

'calculate if a cell is less than a specific value
If ws.Range("A1") < 8 Then
    ws.Range("A1") = 8
Else

End If

End Sub
```

The problem is that only the active worksheet is done and the rest of the worksheets are not looked at. The macro also does not check whether the worksheet should not be included.

Comment: Please, add a worksheet parameter to the `X2` sub and call the function with it. Then, do not use Active sheet... Or use only the first sub, doing what is to be done in its code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want using two subs, please try the next way. Your code only use the active sheet in the second sub:

```
Sub LoopCertain() 'Excel VBA to exclude sheets(1-3)
 Dim sh As Worksheet

 For Each sh In Sheets
    Select Case sh.name
        Case "Blad1", "Blad2", "Blad3"
             'No Code here if excluded
        Case Else
            Call X2(sh)
    End Select
 Next sh
End Sub

Sub X2(ws As Worksheet)
 'calculate if a cell is less than a specific value
  If ws.Range("A1").value < 8 Then ws.Range("A1") = 8
End Sub
```

But for such a simple processing, no need of the second since everything can be done in the first one:

```
Sub LoopCertain() 'Excel VBA to exclude sheets(1-3)
 Dim sh As Worksheet

 For Each sh In Sheets
    Select Case sh.name
        Case "Blad1", "Blad2", "Blad3"
             'No Code here if excluded
        Case Else
            If sh.Range("A1").value < 8 Then sh.Range("A1") = 8        
    End Select
 Next sh
End Sub
```

Comment: I will test your solution. You will hear from me soon.

Comment: Voted for the concept of `Passing object`

Comment: @Waleed whilst I supplied code to pass the object, it was purely for educational purposes. In reality I would personally approach it as FaneDuru has done in this answer and condense it into a single routine. Thanks for the vote though :)

Answer (score 2):

The cleanest way to do this with the code in its current form would be to pass the sheet object to the other sub:

```
Sub LoopCertain() 'Excel VBA to exclude sheets(1-3)
Dim sh As Worksheet

For Each sh In Sheets
    Select Case sh.Name
    Case Is = "Blad1", "Blad2", "Blad3"
        'No Code here if excluded
    Case Else

        Call X2(sh)

    End Select
Next sh
End Sub
```

and then

```
Sub X2(ByVal sh As Worksheet)

    'calculate if a cell is less than a specific value
    If sh.Range("A1") < 8 Then
        sh.Range("A1") = 8
    End If

End Sub
```

---

I've assumed you have a reason in the real-world use for having separate sub-routines, but once you understand this concept of passing the objects around then I would suggest just doing this in a single routine.

Comment: Voted for the concept of `Passing object`